# White background in table section header in iOS14

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, ios14, xcode12

This issue appeared after building to **iOS14** with **xcode12**.

I have a section header with transparent background, on iOS14 it becomes white with new `_UISystemBackgroundView` added to the hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

iOS 14 comes with new two cell configurations:

1. **Content configurations.** `UIContentConfiguration`

As the name suggests, content configurations can help you manipulate the content of the cell like image, text, secondary text, layout metrics and behaviors.

2. **Background configurations** `UIBackgroundConfiguration`

can help with the manipulation of background color, visual effect, stroke, insets and corner radius. All cells will inherit a default background configuration even if we don’t specify one.

### The Solution

To get rid of the default iOS14 white background you need to change the `UITableViewCell` or `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` backgroundConfiguration as follows

```
    // Add this code in your AppDelegate didFinishLauncingWithOptions
    // or you can change configuration of certain subclass using self. backgroundConfiguration = ...
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        var bgConfig = UIBackgroundConfiguration.listPlainCell()
        bgConfig.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().backgroundConfiguration = bgConfig
        //For cell use: UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundConfiguration = bgConfig
    }
```

Read [this article](https://medium.com/@dragos.rotaru9/uitableviewcell-in-ios-14-ef19e877319f) for more

Comment: Husam saves the day!

Comment: Well, that wasn't obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

In your **UITableViewHeaderFooterView / UITableViewCell** custom class - override next method with implementation example:

**Swift:**

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
override func updateConfiguration(using state: UICellConfigurationState) {
    backgroundConfiguration = UIBackgroundConfiguration.clear()
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)updateConfigurationUsingState:(UICellConfigurationState *)state {
    self.backgroundConfiguration = [UIBackgroundConfiguration clearConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: Good solution, Please note that state is kind of class `UIViewConfigurationState` in `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C version of @Husam solution:

```
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
    UIBackgroundConfiguration *bgConfig = [UIBackgroundConfiguration listPlainCellConfiguration];
    bgConfig.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    [UITableViewHeaderFooterView appearance].backgroundConfiguration = bgConfig;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iOS 14's configuration based APIs may disable the functions of those legacy APIs (e.g. `cell.textLabel`, `cell.detailTextLabel`).

To prevent this system behavior, you can set a `backgroundView` (legacy API) to your header/footer/cell, and then set a custom `backgroundColor` for that view.